# Are there flexlm (flexnet) options to reserve for specific user on specific host?

Tags: flexlm

I'm setting up flexlm (Flexara Software - http://www.flexerasoftware.com) with limited licenses for a compiler.  I have been asked to setup flex options to RESERVE one license for a user on a build host.  This user is a build account that is not to be RESERVED on any other build host.  I can't seem to find an option to RESERVE user@host.

Any ideas how I can get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this has been sitting here for a while, but I want to provide an answer since I've been up the same creek many times with FlexNet Options Files.

The `RESERVE` keyword is only for users, so you would have to do something with `INCLUDE` or `EXCLUDE`.

```
 INCLUDE compilerfeature USER buildaccount
 INCLUDE compilerfeature HOST buildserver
```

The above statements do two things:

1. The first line allows the *buildaccount* to access the feature on any host to which they are logged in.
2. The second line allows access to the license if the user is logged into the *buildserver*.

So, implicitly, only the *buildaccount* can access the feature from the *buildserver*.

Unfortunately, this prevents other users from accessing the features, so you will probably want to create groups of users and hosts and use the `RESERVE` keyword to save one license for the *buildaccount*.

If there is a specific keyword in the license file that would identify a single license, you can also use that to allow access to a single license by a single user and/or host.

Comment: Wow...it has been a long time and I've since moved on to another job.  It was great that you answered anyway.  Thanks.  -Brian